# Wrapping generic function calls with one method

Tags: scala

I have something like this:

```
...
case BooleanType => 
  try {
    reader.getBooleanValue()
  } catch {
    case e: IllegalStateException => throwMyException()
  }
case IntegerType => 
  try {
    reader.getIntValue()
  } catch {
    case e: IllegalStateException => throwMyException()
  }
...etc
```

but that's a lot of duplicate code. There must be a way to do something like:

```
case BooleanType => tryGetReaderSafely(reader.getBooleanValue())
case IntegerType => tryGetReaderSafely(reader.getIntValue())
..etc
```

where the method I'm curious about is

```
def tryGetReaderSafely(reader: Reader): Any = {
  try {
    reader.getType // how do I do the correct call here?
  } catch {
    case e: IllegalStateException => throwMyException()
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm passing the function *result* and not the function itself into the call -- I know you can use callbacks but I still am not sure how to use the callback to call the correct `reader.getType` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```scala
def tryGetReaderSafely[T](reader: Reader, f: Reader => T): T =
  try {
    f(reader)
  } catch {
    case e: IllegalStateException => throwMyException()
  }
```

Usage:

```scala
case BooleanType => tryGetReaderSafely(reader, _.getBooleanValue)
case IntegerType => tryGetReaderSafely(reader, _.getIntValue)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Very nice, thank you